# How to fix Car doors only lock and unlock when the key is in the on position in the ignition

Tags: car, repair

I have a 2008 kia sorento lx 4wd and up until yesterday my door locks were working just fine but now they wont lock or unlock unless the key is in the ignition in the on position. I can lock and unlock from the outside as well. What would cause this and how do I fix it?

Comment: So the power locks only work from the door switches and only when the key is in the on position?

Comment: Have you checked you fuses?

Comment: Yes all fuses are good. Yes i can only use my door switches when the key is in the on posotion or the car is running.